# X axis scale for convoluted function in Matlab

Tags: distributions, matlab, convolution

I convoluted gamma distributed having x axis range from 1 to 100 (m=100) and normal distribution with x axis range from -25 to 24 (n=50). By using conv function in MATLAB I got m+n-1 = 149 values. How can I determine the corresponding X axis range for these values. I have attached the sample code for reference.

x= -25:1:24;
x1 = 1:1:100;
normal = normpdf(x,0,1);
gamma = gampdf(x1,20,2);
w = conv(gamma,normal);

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the range of w is [-24:1:124], where -24 is obtained as 1-25 = -24, and 124 is obtained as 100-(-24) = 124.

To verify with your sample code, simply check if w(1) = gamma(1)*normal(1) and w(end) = gamma(end)*normal(end).